# How to use query to filter data in SSRS?

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services

If transaction came from APV, the only columns with amounts are Accounts Payable Trade, Accrued EWT, CIB and Peso will have data.

If transaction is direct to DV (without APV), the columns with amount are Accrued EWT, CIB, Peso, Summary, Input Tax Checking and Total [EWT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmUik.png)

[image]
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjauU.png)

Comment: do you mean, you need some sort of parameter which will decide what data to show?
In your case if parameter value is APV show some data and if parameter value is DV show some other data?

Comment: Exactly sir how can I do it? Thank you

Comment: I added my answer, let me know if this helps.

Comment: What if there is a group column? Thak you

Comment: go ahead give it a try, see what results you get and what do you expect, you might need to tweak expression a bit but your main challenge of filtering/visibility is solved

Comment: ok Thank you so much sir Godbless you

Comment: btw if my below answer helps, do mark it as solved, it will helps others as well!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample data for your use case. This is to show how to achieve your req. You could modify as per your req.

[image]

create parameter as below

[image]

Now create row visibility expression as below

[image]

Note just for simplicity purpose I have made condition as if user selects TR-AFP then show records with only Category="electronics" and if user selects "ALL" then everything except category="electronics"

You just have to adjust according to your column and it's Value

```
=IIF(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value=1 and Fields!category.Value<>"electronics",true,
IIF(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value<>1 and Fields!category.Value="electronics",true,false))
```

Here is how it looks, Look for Right hand side, left hand one is just for your ref as database

[image]

[image]